# IE11 CSS Translate3d shifts DOM element event

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, events

This issue only occurs in IE11 on Hybrid devices like Surface Pro 3!

I have a function that creates an Open and Close menu, which moves a DIV to the right and/or left.
The DIV contains elements with binded events, but when the elements move there is almost a shadow element of the previous position that remains active with the binded events attached to it?

If I click on that shadow then IE repositions the events on the right elements, as illustrated in the below picture.
Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to using animation, CSS translate3d.
I've changed it to translate and it works fine now.